# Distributed Key Generation for multiple key sets

Tags: key-distribution

Is it possible to use a Distributed Key Generation protocol, like the Pedersen DKG, to generate multiple key sets (one secret key and the corresponding public key) instead of only one, but without modifying the exchanged messages?